# Can't deserialize xml properly

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have the following string to deserialize:

```
<result>
<error>
    <errorcode>0</errorcode>
    <errorge>წარმატებით</errorge>
    <errorru>Удачно</errorru>
    <erroren>successfully</erroren>
    <line>89</line>
</error>
<amount>
    <gel>1</gel>
</amount>
<user>01001</user>
<service>MyService</service> // here
<data>
    <nickname>popcorn2</nickname>
    <identification_name>identified</identification_name>
    <wallet_code>5554654</wallet_code>
    <NationalRate>1</NationalRate>
    <RATE>1</RATE>
    <GENERATED_AMOUNT>1</GENERATED_AMOUNT>
    <CURRENCY>GEL</CURRENCY>
</data>
<accoutant>
    <agentBenefit>0</agentBenefit>
    <agentCommission>0.44</agentCommission>
    <clientCommission>0</clientCommission>
</accoutant>
<service>
    <min_amount>0.49</min_amount>
    <max_amount>1500.00</max_amount>
    <currency>GEL</currency>
</service>
<avance>-134206.1500</avance>
<operation_status>0</operation_status>
</result>
```

as you noticed it has two tags named "service" and they have different contents

here is the class that I've been using

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "error")]
public class ErrorInfo
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorcode")]
    public string Errorcode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorge")]
    public string Errorge { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "errorru")]
    public string Errorru { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "erroren")]
    public string Erroren { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "line")]
    public string Line { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "amount")]
public class Amount
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "gel")]
    public string Gel { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "nickname")]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "identification_name")]
    public string Identification_name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "wallet_code")]
    public string Wallet_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NationalRate")]
    public string NationalRate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "RATE")]
    public string RATE { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "GENERATED_AMOUNT")]
    public string GENERATED_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CURRENCY")]
    public string CURRENCY { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "accoutant")]
public class Accoutant
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "agentBenefit")]
    public string AgentBenefit { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "agentCommission")]
    public string AgentCommission { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "clientCommission")]
    public string ClientCommission { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "service")]
public class Service
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "min_amount")]
    public string Min_amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "max_amount")]
    public string Max_amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "error")]
    public ErrorInfo Error { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "amount")]
    public Amount Amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "user")]
    public string User { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "accoutant")]
    public Accoutant Accoutant { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "service")]
    public Service[] Service { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "avance")]
    public string Avance { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "operation_status")]
    public string Operation_status { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to handle service tags as array but it could not work. I was able to get values from the last tag , but not from the first one. both tags are neccessary so i am wondering if there is a way to get values from both tags ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio has this really great feature where you can put your XML in the clipboard and then do Edit -> Paste special -> Paste XML as classes.

If you do that with your XML, it generates the following class for the service tag:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class resultService
{

     private decimal min_amountField;

     private decimal max_amountField;

     private string currencyField;

     private string[] textField;

     /// <remarks/>
     public decimal min_amount
     {
          get
          {
                return this.min_amountField;
          }
          set
          {
                this.min_amountField = value;
          }
     }

     /// <remarks/>
     public decimal max_amount
     {
          get
          {
                return this.max_amountField;
          }
          set
          {
                this.max_amountField = value;
          }
     }

     /// <remarks/>
     public string currency
     {
          get
          {
                return this.currencyField;
          }
          set
          {
                this.currencyField = value;
          }
     }

     /// <remarks/>
     [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
     public string[] Text
     {
          get
          {
                return this.textField;
          }
          set
          {
                this.textField = value;
          }
     }
}
```

If you want to do it manually, the secret seems to be to add a field with the `XmlTextAttribute` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have two different elements with the same name. It won't know which tag belongs where, you have to alter the name to "MyServiceName" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Change your classes as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "result")]
public class Result
{
    // no need XmlElement attribute
    public ServiceComplex ServiceComplex { get; set; }

    // no need XmlElement attribute
    public string ServiceSimple { get; set; }

    // other properties
}

// no need XmlRoot attribute
public class ServiceComplex
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "min_amount")]
    public string Min_amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "max_amount")]
    public string Max_amount { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Instead of `ServiceComplex` and `ServiceSimple`, choose the names that suit you.

Subscribe `XmlSerializer` to `UnknownElement` event:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));
xs.UnknownElement += Xs_UnknownElement;


private static void Xs_UnknownElement(object sender, XmlElementEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Element.Name == "service")
    {
        var result = (Result)e.ObjectBeingDeserialized;
        if (e.Element.ChildNodes.Count == 1)
        {
            result.ServiceSimple = e.Element.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            result.ServiceComplex = new ServiceComplex
            {
                Min_amount = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("min_amount").InnerText,
                Max_amount = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("max_amount").InnerText,
                Currency = e.Element.SelectSingleNode("currency").InnerText
            };
        }
    }
}
```

In the event handler, we manually populate the properties of our class from xml.